# Number of sets $\{x,y\}\subset\{1,2,\dots,100\}$ such that $|x-y|>10$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Here's a question I ran in to recently:

> How many pairs $\{x,y\}\subset\{1,2,\dots,100\}$ are there such that $|x-y|>10$.

I can solve this problem with addition: By assuming $x<y$, we have $89$ possibilities for $y$ when $x=1$, and $88$ possibilities for $y$ when $x=2$, and so forth. This leads to the solution

$$89+88+\dots+1=\frac{90\cdot89}{2}$$

> However, since
>   $$\dfrac{90\cdot 89}{2}=\binom{90}{2},$$
>   it feels like there must be some nice combinatorial argument, but I've been failing to see it. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Not what you want, but consider the square $n\times n$ grid of points with integer coordinates, with lower left corner at $(0,0)$. Then $|x-y|=0$ is the $45^\circ$ diagonal  through $(0,0)$. And $|x-y|=1$ is the next two diagonals, and so on. Delete these up to the two $|x-y|=10$ diagonals. We are left with two triangle of points. Move the right-hand one so that its bottom left corner is just below the bottom left corner of the left-hand one. We get an $89\times 90$ rectangle of grid points.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Every such pair can be obtained in a unique way by choosing two numbers from $\{1,2,\ldots,90\}$ and adding $10$ to the larger one.

Comment: Very nice and elegant. +1

Answer (score 3):

Line up 100 dots are in a row, so any choice of two dots with at least 10 dots between them

will give us such a pair. $\;\;$Let $d_1, d_2, d_3$ be the number of dots in the 3 gaps created,

so $d_1+d_2+d_3=98$ with $d_2\ge10.\;\;$  If we let $e_1=d_1, e_3=d_3,$ and $e_2=d_2-10$,

we get the equation $e_1+e_2+e_3=88,\;\;$ and this has $\dbinom{90}{2}$ solutions in nonnegative integers.